# ORA-00904 : invalid identifier in nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in oracle sql and I want to use this simple nested query that calcule the er_cli with highest er_val value(er_val is not a number) but when I try to execute it it shows "ORA-00904:"MAX_VAL":invalid identifier". I looked in some examples but nothing helps.

```
 select er_cli,max(max_val)
  from (select er_cli,count(er_val)
        from f_entrel
        group by er_cli) max_val
  group by er_cli;
```

Comment: max_val is defined as a table alias here, but you use it as a column alias.

Comment: If er_val is not a number, then what is the definition of "highest"? Counting the number of letters? Or maybe its numbers stored as a string? If the latter, then cast as numeric.

Comment: Do you want the `er_cli` with the highest (however you define that) `er_val` value, or the one with the *most* `er_val` values - which seems plausible as you are currently counting them? Do you only want to count distinct values; and how would you want to handle a tie? Please edit your question to include sample data and expected results (as formatted text, not images; and not as comments), and to explain your logic.

Comment: So, the er_val columns are of type varchar so i want to see every distinct  er_cli column how many er_val values has. For example I have 10 distinct er_cli values and for each one of them there are different number of er_val values. I want to see the er_cli column with the most er_val values

Comment: It would be better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73909864/edit) to provide more information and explanation - and preferably sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

As jarlh's comment said,you have use `max_value` as a table alias but then you using `COUNT` on it,below is a reference for you

```
 select m.er_cli,max(m.cnt)
  from (select er_cli,count(er_val) as cnt
        from f_entrel
        group by er_cli) m
  group by m.er_cli;
```

---

Update:

If you want to get the max value with `er_cli`,you can use `order by` and `limit` to do it

```
SELECT m.er_cli,m.cnt
   FROM
   (
    SELECT er_cli,count(er_val) AS cnt,rownumber
            FROM f_entrel
            GROUP BY er_cli
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
   ) m
   WHERE m.rownumber=1
```

Comment: You was faster than me. I believe that (column name missing) is the issue.

Comment: that works but i want only the er_cli with the highest er_val. When I execute this code it shows me every single er_cli. I tried to remove the group by statement but then oracle shows me ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: @ВалентинД., add some sample table data and the expected result to your question, all as formatted text (no images, no links.)

Comment: A60043XX 1169
 A6004FHM 1033
 A600466N 670
 A6004RXF 403
Thats an example of an exit with this code. But i want only the first line

Comment: Use a WITH common table expression instead to make this easier to development.

Comment: That does not work neither. When I include group by statement again shows everything and when i do not include it oracle shows 00937 error

Comment: WITH A as ( what the nested query does today )
SELECT (the current outer query) joined with A

Answer (score 1):

As already said elsewhere, you are mixing up table (or table expression/inline view) aliases and column aliases. But showing the maximum count for each `er_cli` wouldn't change the result anyway.

> i want to see every distinct er_cli column how many er_val values has.

That's what your subquery (inline view) does:

```
select er_cli, count(er_val) as val_count
from f_entrel
group by er_cli
```

With some dummy data, running that on its own would give a result like:

| ER_CLI | VAL_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 4 |

> I want to see the er_cli column with the most er_val values

You could use your subquery approach:

```
select er_cli, val_count
from (
  select er_cli, count(er_val) as val_count
  from f_entrel
  group by er_cli
  order by count(er_val) desc
)
where rownum = 1
```

Order by the count *descending* means the highest count comes first. The `rownum` filter then limits the result to the first row from that ordered subquery.

Or in recent versions of Oracle you can order and limit the results from that query directly:

```
select er_cli, count(er_val) as val_count
from f_entrel
group by er_cli
order by count(er_val) desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Either way, the same dummy data would give:

| ER_CLI | VAL_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 9 |

So far, if you have two `er_cli` values with the same number of `er_val` values, you will only see one of them, and which you see is indeterminate - it could change between executions of the same query. It would be better to enforce some arbitrary secondary order, just so you get consistent results, by for example changing them to `order by count(er_val) desc, er_cli` - so if there is a tie you'll see the lower of the `er_cli` values that are tied.

Alternatively with the `fetch` syntax you can get both tied values:

```
select er_cli, count(er_val) as val_count
from f_entrel
group by er_cli
order by count(er_val) desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

which with the same data plus another `er_cli` with 9 `er_val` values would give:

| ER_CLI | VAL_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 9 |
| 3 | 9 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9OwRI9hd)

Note that you don't have to include the count in the final result - if you don't want it then just leave it off the (outer) select list. And you could aggregate the tied `er_cli` values into a string if you wanted to, with `listagg()` - but it depends how this result needs to be presented or consumed.